# Select only nearest records in matching result set when using $lt

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection where an item_id exists for multiple location_id and created_date.

I want to get all items in specific locations where created_date $lte 2018-11-21.
I want $lte to match only one record and don't match further, but the problem is when using $lte it won't stop to only first matching row rather it will fetch all the rows which have lower created date.

```
{
  "created_date" : {
    $lte : ISODate('2018-11-21'),
  },
  "location_id" : {
    $in : [
      "5a7c2cc414d4882bb9378373",
      "5a7c0c6714d488216a60b033"
      ]
  }
}
```

**Sample Data**

```
{
  "item_id" : ObjectId("5a81677f14d4880dc4017c74"),
  "created_date" : ISODate("2018-11-10T11:00:00Z"),
  "location_id" : "5a7c0c6714d488216a60b033"
},
{
  "item_id" : ObjectId("5a81677f14d4880dc4017c74"),
  "created_date" : ISODate("2018-11-09T10:00:00Z"),
  "location_id" : "5a7c0c6714d488216a60b033"
},
{
  "item_id" : ObjectId("5a81677f14d4880dc4017c74"),
  "created_date" : ISODate("2018-11-10T11:00:00Z"),
  "location_id" : "5a7c0c6714d488216a60b011"
},
{
  "item_id" : ObjectId("5a81677f14d4880dc4017c74")
  "created_date" : ISODate("2018-11-09T11:00:00Z"),
  "location_id" : "5a7c0c6714d488216a60b011",
}
```

**I want only first match in $lte like**

```
{
 "item_id" : ObjectId("5a81677f14d4880dc4017c74"),
 "created_date" : ISODate("2018-11-10T11:00:00Z"),
 "location_id" : "5a7c0c6714d488216a60b033"
},
{
  "item_id" : ObjectId("5a81677f14d4880dc4017c74"),
  "created_date" : ISODate("2018-11-10T11:00:00Z"),
  "location_id" : "5a7c0c6714d488216a60b011"
}
```

I want to avoid the group as there are more than 3 million records and group ll slow down the query, is there any other way to stop further matching $lte when a matching record is found?

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: I think findOne() will help you